# Tizen - Best approach to create NFC data Exchange

Tags: nfc, tizen-wearable-sdk

Does Samsung Tizen support native NFC app. I'd like a native app that sits on the watch to read scanned tag and do a data exchange ?

If it has to be done in html5, does it support NFC data exchange ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Samsung Tizen support native NFC app. I'd like a native app that
>   sits on the watch to read scanned tag and do a data exchange ?

Yes it does. Please refer to the Wearable Native [reference](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application/web-application-2.3.1?redirect=http%3A//developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/web_api_reference.htm)

To read a tag you should take a look at the **TAG** APIs. If you also want to perform data exchange then you should take a look at the **Peer to Peer** APIs.

> If it has to be done in html5, does it support NFC data exchange ?

Similar functionality is supported using the web APIs. Take a look at the **NFCTag** and **NFCPeer** interfaces in the Web API [reference](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application/web-application-2.3.1?redirect=http%3A//developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/web_api_reference.htm).

A nice start (Native development) point could be to check the existing tutorials for NFC [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/native-application/network/nfc).

[Here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/communication/nfc) you will find the tutorials for the web APIs.

Comment: do you know any html tutorials for this ?

Comment: so NFC is done with javascript right ? im not doing native app as its too much work to learn, sticking with html for tizen wearable.  The functions im seeing here: https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.tutorials/html/web/tizen/communication/nfc_tutorial_w.htm   are javaScript right ? so I'll put them in my js folder right?

Comment: I have edited my answer with the examples for the web counterpart.

Comment: Has anyone actually tested reading NFC tags with a wearable running Samsung Tizen? I'm asking because this compatibility list suggests that no wearable is actually supporting NFC tags: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/device-compatibility.html

Answer (score 2):

The currently accepted answer is not correct. Both NFCTag and NFCPeer APIs are not supported on Samsung Gear devices.

Just SE (secure element) API - used for processing payments - is.

It's possible to verify that when registering for notifications callbacks as per the following [guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/nfc#work). Functions `nfc_manager_set_tag_discovered_cb` and `nfc_manager_set_p2p_target_discovered_cb` returns NOT SUPPORTED.

The following SO questions mentions the same problem:
[NFC Tag not working on Gear S2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002194/nfc-tag-not-working-on-gear-s2)

Answer (score 0):

You can develop rich Web applications(HTML5) using NFC available on Samsung Gear S2. Yes it does support data exchange.

You can follow following links for more info

[NFC Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.guides/html/web/tizen/communication/nfc_w.htm)

[NFC API Details](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/nfc.html)

[NFC Tutorial/Code](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.tutorials/html/web/tizen/communication/nfc_tutorial_w.htm)

Refer this link for app **[Tizen Wearable Web Device API Reference](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/index.html)**.

Comment: i wish there was a actual tutorial on it, im kind of new. do you know any ?